# Supporting multiple database's - returning common object from query's

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to create an app the can handle multiple database types. 
So far I have created my Interface like so. Its very simple and all the database will do is Load and Save a profile

```
public interface IDataManager
{
    Profile LoadProfile(int profileId);

    bool SaveProfile(Profile profile);

    bool CreateDatabase();

    bool OpenConnection();

    bool CloseConnection();
}
```

and lets just say the `Profile` class for the above looks like this.

```
public class Profile 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is what is the best way to make it so that all the implementations of `IDataManager` return the same object types?

Here is an example of what I mean by this. (This is not quality code its just an example)

I create an `SQLite` class that implements `IDataManager` and then create an instance.

```
public IDataManager DataManager = new SQLiteDataManager();
```

Later in the code I want to load a `Profile` so I call the `LoadProfile`.

```
Profile profile = DataManager.LoadProfile(1);
```

My SQLite implementation of the `LoadProfile` method looks like this

```
public Profile LoadProfile(int profileId)
{
        // Copied and pasted from a WinRT app
        using (var conn = new global::SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new global::SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _sqlpath))
        {
            var tmp = conn.Table<PROFILE>().First(x => x.ID == profileId);
        }

    // do something and return
}
```

Now as you can see the return type from the query (`tmp = type PROFILE`) is not the same type as the `LoadProfile` method return type (`Profile`). 
Do I have to convert `tmp` to `Profile`? which means it must be done in all the methods with return types, and for every different database implementation. or is there a better way of doing this?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You are recreating (or back pedaling) on what already exists.  MySql, OleDB etc all implement the methods and such defined in `System.Data.Common` in a way specific to their needs. Adding more abstraction will hide all the special goodies that some have.

Comment: Why not use a common class library that all of your data layers can then reference? That way you don't have multiple implementations of `Profile` floating around.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Entity Framework you can just use the provider for the db type you will be using but keep all the api and models the same

[A list of Entity Framework providers for various databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865352/a-list-of-entity-framework-providers-for-various-databases)

Comment: Then use Dapper or some other ORM, that is the job of a ORM, to do all that mapping work from `PROFILE` to `Profile` for you so you don't have to write it yourself.